# window button get disappers when opening window popup second time

Tags: extjs4.1

on click of button i am opening one popup with abort button. and sending request to server after i get response i open new popup window with download button and close the first one. at first time it is working fine. but second time my abort and download button getting disappeared.  when i inspect popup i can see abort n download button present at code side but not visible on user interface.

```
if (_data.status == "inProcess" ) {
            exportPopup.show();
        } else if (_data.status == "success") {
            var height= exportPopup.getHeight();
            exportPopup.close();
            downloadPopup = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                name: 'downloadReport',
                header: false,
                id: 'downloadPopWin',
                constrain: true,
                closable: false,
                width: 400,
                height: height,
                resizable: false,
                bodyStyle: 'background-color : white;',
                buttonAlign: 'center',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    pack: 'center'
                }, 
                items: 
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    itemId:'exportStatus',
                    margin : '50 0 0 0',
                    text: 'Export completed.',
                    //style: 'font-weight: bold;'
                },
               buttons:[
                {
                    //xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Download',
                    id: "btnDownloadReport",
                    //margin : '20 0 20 180',
                    handler: function(_button) {
                        downloadPopup.close();
                        ReportUtil.downloadReportData(me, _data);
                    }
                }                   
                ]

            });
            downloadPopup.show();
        }
```

Comment: please provide me the fiddle and in your question there is no extrapopup code also please provide that also

Answer (score 0):

remove closable: false, and try closable false means we cannot close the window

docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closable

Comment: I think mostly closable: false is the problem remove closable it default value is true so it will work